# CakePHP How to save manytomany

Tags: cakephp, many-to-many, cakephp-model

I have the following view for adding Properties to a product.

```
echo $this->Form->create('Product', array('role' => 'form'));
echo $this->Form->input('ProductProperty.Property', array(
    'multiple' => 'multiple',
    'type' => 'select',
));
echo $this->Form->input('id', array('type' => 'hidden'));
echo $this->Form->end('Submit);
```

Which action on the Product Model do I have to call that Properties as well as ProductProperties are created? The ProductProperty is a mapping Model for the Product and the Property table.

```
array(
    'ProductProperty' => array(
        'Property' => array(
            (int) 0 => '4',
            (int) 1 => '5'
        )
    ),
    'Product' => array(
        'id' => '1'
    )
)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: 
a foreign key constraint fails (`product_properties`, CONSTRAINT `product_properties_id_fk2` FOREIGN KEY (`property_id`) REFERENCES `properties` (`id`))

SQL Query: INSERT INTO `product_properties` (`product_id`) VALUES (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In CakePHP many-to-many called HABTM
It is here in the cookbook: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm

You should have 2 models, the product and the property, and 3 database table: products, properties ans products_properties. Than define the association, and you are done.

Comment: I use it this way but get the error mentioned above and don't Why the foreign key conflicts there.

Comment: Where this array came from? You created it manually? It supposed to be something like array('Product' => array('id' => 1), 'Property' => array(array('id' => 4) ,array('id' => 5))). But you have other problems also. I would recommend you to bake your models, controllers and views for Products and Properties and investigate the code and the form of the submitted data.

Answer (score -1):

Try to set `$this->Model->recursive = 1;`

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: this post is old i think he used cakephp 2.x...which version are you in so i can help you..For this answer there is no information just use set recursive to 1 before your Find().....